# Xcode link error with libcommonCrypto.dylib

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

With the latest Xcode, my app is running fine in simulator, but I get this error when I run it on device:

[image]

I do not have it linked in my binaries. I do have `libz.dylib`. Here is what I am linking against:

[image]

Why would my project be trying to link against something for cryptography if I'm not doing that? How to fix?

Comment: Does your project have any dependancies? Is it a workspace with other projects in it?

Comment: no, it's a standalone project. to answer Kevin Cao's question, it is iOS sdk 6 in Build Settings, though I cannot run it on device with iOS 5 or iOS 6, yet it runs fine in simulators for iOS 5 and 6. Architecture in Build Settings is set to Standard.

Comment: Check your linking settings within the build-settings; especially `Linking` -> `Other Linker Flags`, sounds as if there was a -lcommonCrypto in there - make sure you check the `target` specific settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed Xcode and the problem disappeared.

Comment: [Better Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490304/link-against-the-umbrella-framework) ,as it says  remove libcommonCrypto.dylib,and replace by adding SystemConfiguration.framework.It worked for me,might be useful to someone.I was getting Linker Error saying _gettingLink against the umbrella framework 'System.framework' instead_.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using encryption into your code. Please add `libcommonCrypto.dylib` framework into your code.

Comment: I am not using encryption. however, regardless, I cannot find libcommonCrypto.dylib when I go to link to other frameworks. but I shouldn't have to anyway -- again, the app is running fine on simulator.