# Link against the umbrella framework

Tags: ios, networking, flurry, libsystem

I got ios app where i want to implement Flurry-analytics.

After importing Flurry and ling libsystem_network.dylib

I got this problem which cannot solve

```
ld: cannot link directly with /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib.  Link against the umbrella framework 'System.framework' instead. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In google i find the same problem with `libcommonCrypto.dylib` here and in some other places:

[CommonCrypto isn't building for arch armv7 iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547711/commoncrypto-isnt-building-for-arch-armv7-ios)

but this doesn't help me

Any ides? thnx

Comment: Do you have their latest version? You can always just remove armv7s from your project - the newer devices can use armv7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply change `libsystem_network.dylib` for `SystemConfiguration.framework` and that works for Flurry

Comment: Hi i changed like this but still error coming is there any other ways to clear that

Answer (score 12):

When using CommonCrypto in a framework, I was getting a similar error durning linking with libcommonCypto.dylib, changed to Security.framework and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Xcode build phases]

You can try set Link Binary With Libraries like this, it works for me.
There's a demo, it's called Socket.io-with-iOS, you can checkout out it.